# PHP Session across pages

Tags: php, session

have this question in mind. I know there are a lot questions like this on the internet, but none of them seem to do the trick for me :(

So I'm planning on making an adminpanel on a website. You enter by going through a login screen, when the name+pass is correct an session is made. On the other adminpages I'll test if this session is set, by this I'll know if the user can access the page or not.

Inlog.php (simplyfied)

```
<?php session_start(); ?> <html ...
```

then after lots of controls

```
    if ($adminpwd == $pass) {
    session_regenerate_id();
    $_SESSION["mysessionname"] = $name;
    $tijd = date('H:i:s', strtotime('+ 30 minutes'));
    $_SESSION["E4A_einde"] = $tijd;
    session_write_close();
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.location = 'myotheradminpage'</script>";
}
```

My other php pages include this script

```
<?php session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION["mysessionname"])) {

session_destroy();
echo '<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript"> window.alert("no session found") </SCRIPT>';
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.location = 'myloginpage'</script>";
        }
```

With this element, if the session is not set there's a redirect, if the session is set the other code on the php page wil be triggered.

But the fact is that Every single time i'm redirected again to my loginpage. so my session is not set :s Can't figure out why so please help me out.

I tried a lot of thins with on every page to add the session_start() methode, I tried to regenerated the session id before I set the sessions, but nothing works..

Comment: @itachi I've PHP eyes...lol just saw and removed my comment

Comment: look at [header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) there is a method to redirect in server side.

Comment: i didn't had schooling in php, so I'll did my redirects with the things I know. Would like to have some real answers in stead of some lols.. but thanks for the tip itachi

Comment: there are other codes involve in this. `$tijd = date('H:i:s', strtotime('+ 30 minutes'));
    $_SESSION["E4A_einde"] = $tijd;` this show you are probably destroying somewhere too. Plz show those.

Comment: You need to use the `header` method @itachi mentioned or people will be able to use your admin panel by disabling javascript.

Comment: @itachi i didn't destroy anything yet of sessions. this is my complete code (for this event)

Comment: in the other php page, (the 2nd one); do a `var_dump($_SESSION);` after `session_start();`

Comment: shows:  array(0){}, then my alertbox is triggered and get redirected again to my loginpage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your initial `session_start` before the HTML, try setting this:

```
<?php session_start();  
$_SESSION["mysessionname"]; ?>
<html ...
```

This will declare your session variable before anything runs.

Let me know if this works.

Comment: `php` does not need this procedure.

Comment: I'll set this as best answer. I had a <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC " .. rule too in my page and this was set before the php session_start. So technically I set the phprule before the html but yet.. Thanx all for the advise, you too itachi!

Answer (score 0):

Drop the `session_regenerate_id`. It sends another cookie, but output has been already sent.

Also drop the call to `session_write_close`. It would happen in the end of the script anyway and this micro-optimization has negative impact on the quality of the code base. If you have concurrency issues, go with `memcached` session store, but you are far away from there.

Also drop the `session_destroy` call. If he is not authorized, then he is not authorized. Your logic here suggests purging an already empty session.

Comment: Regenerating on every request might be encouraged, otherwise it serves  a little of purpose.